# Trying to center the navbar, but not working

Tags: html, css, ghost-blog

I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS, and I'm trying to center the navbar, but it's not working :( I'm making a personal website for ghost CMS. I already removed the `float` part in the CSS code and changed `text-align: right` to `center` under `nav`. I also added `text-align: center` under `ul.menu li a` as well, but the issue persists for some reason. Need help!

**HTML**

```
<!-- start: #header -->
<header id="header" class="grid-container">

    <div class="menu-mobile">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

    <!-- start: .menu-wrapper -->
    <div class="menu-wrapper">
    
        <div class="">
        
            {{#if @site.logo}}
                <div class="logo" ><a href="{{@site.url}}"><img src="{{@site.logo}}" alt="{{@site.title}}" ></a></div>
            {{else}}
                <div class="logo text-logo">
                    <a href="{{@site.url}}" class="title large white no-margin">{{@site.title}}</a>
                </div>
            {{/if}}

            <br>

            {{!-- <div class="share-buttons hide-on-tablet hide-on-mobile hide-on-desktop-sm">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </div> --}}


            {{#if @member}}
                <a class="subscribe button red hide-on-tablet hide-on-mobile" data-members-signout>{{t "Sign Out"}} <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>
            {{else}}
                <a href="{{@site.url}}/subscribe" class="subscribe button red hide-on-tablet hide-on-mobile">{{t "Subscribe"}} <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></a>
            {{/if}}
   
            
            <!-- start: .main-nav -->
            <nav class="main-nav grid-container grid-parent">
                
                {{navigation}}
                
            </nav>
            <!-- end: .main-nav -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="border hide-on-tablet hide-on-mobile"></div>
        
        </div>      
        
        <div class="clear"></div>
        
    </div>
    <!-- end: .menu-wrapper -->
    
    <div class="clear"></div>

</header>
<!-- end: #header -->


<div id="form-lang" data-results-title="{{t 'Results for your search'}}"></div>

<div class="hide-on-desktop hide-on-tablet hide-on-mobile">
    <div id="search-lightbox" class="mfp-hide grid-container grid-small grid-parent">
        <h4 class="title small white textcenter fw-normal hide-on-mobile hide-on-tablet">{{{t "Press {key} to close" key="<span>ESC</span>"}}}</h4>
        <div class="search-wrapper section">                
            <form action="{{@site.url}}" method="get" class="search-form">
                <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="" class="search-field" placeholder="{{t "Type to start your seach..."}}" required>
                <button type="submit" class="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="search-results" class="grid-container section"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* @group Header */

#header{
    div.menu-mobile{ display: none; }
    div.menu-wrapper{ 
        padding: 50px 0px 0;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    .logo {
        // max-width: 375px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px auto;
        // float: left;
        a {
            display: block;
            // font-size: 28px;
            // line-height: 40px;
            color: #fff;
            i.fa{
                margin-right: 10px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                position: relative;
                top: -3px;
            }
            img {
                display: inline-block;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: 800;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        }
        &.text-logo{
            margin-top: 12px;
        }
    }

    // Main Navigation
    nav{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
        text-align: center;
        // float: right;
        margin-top: 5px;
        ul.menu{ font-size: 0px; }
        ul.menu li{
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 20px 15px 20px;
            position: relative;
        }
        ul.menu li a{
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: $title-font-family;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 1.45;
            letter-spacing: 0.5px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            color: #fff;
            &.lightbox{
                background: none;
                &:hover{
                    transform: translateY(-2px);
                }
            }
        }
        ul.menu li a:hover,
        ul.menu li.current-menu-item > a, ul.menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a{
            // color: $green;
            // text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
            // text-shadow: 2px 3px 0px #898999;
            background-size: 100% 4px;
            // background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba($red, 1) 0%, rgba($red, 1) 100%);
            &:after{
                opacity: 1;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
        ul.sub-menu{
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 100%;
            z-index: 100;
            padding: 15px 0;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 7px;
            min-width: 250px;
            text-align: left;
            left: -10px;
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(#000, 0.15);
            transform: translateY(-15px);
            @include transition(500ms);
            li{ display: block; padding: 0; }
            li a{
                display: block;
                font-family: $font-family;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: 500;
                color: $text-color;
                padding: 10px 25px;
                &:hover{
                    color: $text-color;
                    background: #f6f6f6;
                }
            }
            ul.sub-menu{
                left: 100%;
                top: -15px;
                transform: scale(1) translateX(-10px);
            }
        }
        ul.menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu{
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
        }
    }
    .subscribe.button{
        float: right;
        margin: 16px 0 0 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        .fa{
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-top: -1px;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }
    .share-buttons{
        float: right;
        background: rgba(#000, 0.15);
        padding: 5px 25px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 101;
        a{
            display: inline-block;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 0 7px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            &:hover{ transform: translateY(-2px); }
        }
    }

    div.border{
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(#fff, 0.25);
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

}

@keyframes headerPinnedSlideDown{
    0% {top:-100%;}
    100%{top:0;}
}

/* @end */
```

Comment: as always: dont use `float` for styling purpose. `float` is for floating images within a text-block. For everything else it would be a mis-used hack (with exeption of e-mail templates). Use Flexbox instead!

Comment: Not a theme that I made myself. I'm editing it.

Comment: Website that I'm working on: https://johnseong.info

Comment: You can Use bootstrap for navbar and check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-align-navbar-items-to-center-using-bootstrap-4/ may help you !